# Cannot connect to OrientDB localhost database through console

Tags: database, orientdb

I'm trying to look for it help in their documentation but with no luck.
Anyways, I've made a database through their OrientDB Studio for the localhost.
But I'm not exactly sure how to connect to it through console nor could I find where it is being stored :/

What I've tried and the error I'm getting:
Connect remote:localhost/testdb admin admin

> Cannot change command-cache.json

Connect remote:localhost:2480/testdb

> Cannot create a connection to remote server address

Connect remote:localhost/database/testdb

> Cannot change command-cache.json

Comment: Which version? Silly question: is the server still running?

Comment: Yeah the server is up and running, and I can connect to a database like I've made a local one and it's fine but I don't know how to connect to the ones made on localhost through orient studio and the version is v2.2.25

Comment: from console: connect remote:host/dbname admin admin should works. in your case: connect remote:localhost/testdb admin admin. The database name is case sensitive, so if your db name is testDB, modify the name.